# Converting our Unicode to Persian in ArcGIS scripting by ArcPy

Tags: python, arcpy

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
env.workspace=r'I:\amozesh\samplegdb.gdb'
infeature=r'I:\amozesh\samplegdb.gdb\blocksclip'
cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infeature,['layer'])
cursor.next()
```

output
`(u'\u0627\u0631\..........\u0631',)`

How can I print it out using the Persian language?

Comment: cursor.next() is returning a tuple containing the raw string unicode characters. To print them, simply `print(u'\u0627\u0631\u0627\u0636\u06cc')`

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the cursor.next() method returns a tuple of the raw string unicode characters. To print the unicode text, I suggest altering your code to the following:

```
cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infeature,['layer'])
for row in cursor:
    print(row[0])
```

or

```
cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infeature,['layer'])
for row in cursor:
    arcpy.AddMessage(row[0])
```